# Spark scala join dataframe within a dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, join, apache-spark-sql

I have a requirement where I need to join dataframes A and B and calculate a column and use that calculated value in another join between the same 2 dataframes with different Join conditions.

e.g.:

```
 DF_Combined = A_DF.join(B_DF,'Join-Condition',"left_outer").withColumn(col1,'value')
```

after doing the above I need to do the same join but use the value calculated in the previous join.

```
 DF_Final=A_DF.join(B_DF,'New join COndition',"left_outer").withcolumn(col2,DF_Combined.col1*vol1*10)
```

When I try to do this I get a Cartesian product issue.

Comment: It's really not clear whet you're asking. Can you expand your question with some more concrete examples? A few rows of example data in tables (relevant columns only) might be helpful, along with the result you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a column that is not present in dataframe. I mean when you do `A_DF.join(B_DF,...` in the resulting dataframe you only have columns from `A_DF` and `B_DF`. If you want to have the new column - you need to use `DF_Combined`.

From your question i believe you don't need to have another join, but you have 2 possible options:
1. When you do first join - at this place calculate `vol1*10`. 
2. After join do `DF_Combined.withColumn...`.

But please remember - `withColumn(name, expr)` creates a column with a `name`setting value to result of `expr`. So `.withcolumn(DF_Combined.col1,vol1*10)` does not make sense.

Comment: I am not able to make the join as required. I ll post my answer in some time. Thanks for your suggestion though